# How to change visited tab color in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic app with 'tabs' template .
I want to change the visited tab color , how to do that .

PS: I am not pointing to currently active tab .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override this css and check.

```
.tab-item.tab-item-active, .tab-item.active, .tab-item.activated {
   color: red !important;
```

}